# Java: hibernate in web app - unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, pojo

I am struggling strange problem with Hibernate in web application, although I don't encounter it in test standalone application.

*faces-config.xml*

```
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>businessUserData</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>org.beans.BusinessUserDataHibernate</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>daoUserData</property-name>
            <value>#{daoUserData}</value>
        </managed-property> 
    </managed-bean>     
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>daoUserData</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>org.data.source.DAOuserDataHibernate</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
```

*DAOuserDataHibernate.getUserData()* - which I am using as service class in BusinessUserDataHibernate class

```
     public UserData getUserData(String userName){
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();     
        UserData userData=null;
        try{
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            userData = (UserData)session.get(UserData.class, userName);
            tx.commit();            
                    session.close();
            return userData;
        }
        catch(HibernateException hEx){ return null; }                           
    }
```

*hibernate.cfg.xml*

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mySQLdb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">...</property>
        <property name="connection.password">...</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping resource="UserData.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

*UserData.hbm.xml*

```
<hibernate-mapping package="org.hibernate">

    <class name="UserData" table="UserData">
        <id name="userId" column="id" type="string"/>
        <property name="xmlData" type="clob"/>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

My imported jars

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiCMk.jpg

When I run application in from as standalone test application it works fine (hibernate is picking data or writes to DB depending on DAO method I call). When I deploy it to WAR and run it on *Glasfish3* server it dumps

*Stack Trace*

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:433)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1313)
    at org.data.source.DAOuserHibernate.getAllUsers(DAOuserHibernate.java:61)
    at org.spring.beans.BusinessUserHibernate.getAllUsers(BusinessUserHibernate.java:33)
```

I tried different ways, also with Spring support but eventually I end up with this exception. It seems it is related somehow on building *sessionFactory*. Could you please help me in this matter.

Thank you in advance
Marcin

Answer (score 1):

This will probably is not your case but Hibernate throws this exception when using java 11 instead of expected Java 8

Answer (score 0):

I got a same problem but it was solved after adding javassist.jar. I used maven for dependency management. I added like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

pls check try tot change your javssist version